# Merging arrays where IDs match? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Before I go into what I am trying to do, let me explain the issue. ...so, I have a form, with 10 items, so like

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1">Item 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Item 2</label>
```

and so on.

So that is being populated from an array from one table like so

```
 array(
  '1' => 'Item 1',
  '2' => 'Item 2',
 )
```

and so on.

Now, I have another table that stores numbers like 1,3,5,6. 
These are the id's of items in the form that should be checked. So in the html, any ids that match, should be checked.

So..what I was going to try to do was take that list of numbers, explode it, put it into an array like

```
array(
 '1' => 'checked',
 '3' => 'checked',
 '5' => 'checked'
 )
```

Then finally, merge those arrays so it would be come something like

```
array(
'item 1' => array('Item 1', '1', 'checked'),
'item 2' => array('Item 2, '2'),
'item 3' => array('Item 3', '3', 'checked'));
```

And then populate my form with that.

Is this crazy? I feel like there must be a more simple way to do this. An also, how would I even do that with those arrays? That is a little more extreme array juggling that I have done before. Any advice would be great. Thank you.

EDIT - Also...would Javascript be a better option? That would be easy, but I had it in mind to keep this in PHP in case of any browsers without Javascript (which would pretty much break the app anyways). Is Javascript a legit or maybe even better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A change to the checked items table may be in order, but a simplified version of what you already have to work with the data as it comes out of the database:

```
$checked_ids = explode(',', $checked_rows);

foreach($item_rows as $item) {
    $checked = in_array($item['id'], $checked_ids) ? 'checked' : '';
    // your checkbox input below using $checked
    echo $item['id'] . " " . $checked . " " . $item['name'];
}
```

If you need to reuse this, consider making it a function that takes the rows and the checked ids.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you can do:

```
$checkbox =array(
    '1' => 'Item 1',
    '2' => 'Item 2',
    '3' => 'Item 3'
);

$checked = array(
    '1' => 'checked',
    '3' => 'checked',
    '5' => 'checked'
);



$output1 = array();

foreach ($checkbox as $key => $value) {

    if (array_key_exists($key,$checked) && $checked[$key] == 'checked') {
        $result = array($value,$key,'checked');
    } else {
        $result = array($value,$key);
    }
    $output1[$value] = $result;
}

var_dump($output1);
```